# how to produce TypeScript definitions for both commonjs and globals?

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, commonjs, global

I have a TypeScript project written with the commonjs module system that I would like to make it usable also from globals (no modules).

I can use webpack to bundle it and publish into global namespace, but the definitions (`.d.ts`) are not compatible with globals (due to the "export" keyword).

So how do I create the `.d.ts` files for global usage? Is there a quick way or should I have to write them by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a function without any export.

Not tested but it should work :

```
declare namespace mynamespace
{
    interface myFunctionInGlobalNamespace {
        ...
    }
}


declare function myFunctionInGlobalNamespace(): mynamespace.myFunctionInGlobalNamespace;
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question, which investigates _existing_ code.

Comment: This seems to be the way to declare in a typings that a function is available into the global namespace.